# Backpropagation - softmax derivative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have a question on the backpropagation in a simple neural network (I am trying to derive the derivative for the backpropagation).

Suppose that the network is simple like so (forward pass):

$$\begin{aligned}z_1 &= xW_1 + b_1  & (1) \\
  a_1 &= \tanh{(z_1)} & (2) \\
z_2 & = a_1W_2 + b_2 & (3)\\
a_2 & = \text{softmax}(z_2)=\hat{y}_n & (4) \\
l_n & = \log{(\hat{y}_n)} & (5) \\
PL_n & = l_n\dot{y}_n^T & (6) \\
L & = -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n \in N} PL_n & (7)
\end{aligned}
$$

So only one hidden layer. Let the dimensions be the following:

$x$ is $1 \times 2$, $W_1$ is $2 \times 500$, $b_1$ is $1 \times 500$, $a_1$ is $1 \times 500$, $W_2$ is $500 \times 2$, $b_2$ is $1 \times 2$, then $\log{(\hat{y_n})}$ is $1 \times 2$, then $\dot{y}_n^T$ is $2 \times 1$.

Then the backpropagation algorithm (for a single sample), for this staged computation would proceed as follows (equipped with the knowledge that the derivative of $X$ whose dimensions are $N \times M$ will preserve those dimensions):

$$\begin{aligned}
dPL_n & = -1/N & (7) \\
d\dot{y}^T_n & = l_n^T  dPL_n & (6) \\
dl_n & = \dot{y}^T_n dPL_n & (6) \\
d\hat{y}_n & = 1/\hat{y}_n & (5)
\end{aligned}
$$

Backpropagation equation $(5)$ above is a bit of an abuse of notation, but what I am trying to say that it is a vector, whose values are $[1/\hat{y}_n^{(1)}, 1/\hat{y}_n^{(2)}]$. But I am stuck at this step. Because I am not sure about the softmax. I have found [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative). Which tells me that if $a_2$ is the resulting softmax vector, then I can take following four derivatives: $\frac{\partial a_2^{(1)}}{\partial a_2^{(1)}}$,$\frac{\partial a_2^{(1)}}{\partial a_2^{(2)}}$,$\frac{\partial a_2^{(2)}}{\partial a_2^{(1)}}$,$\frac{\partial a_2^{(2)}}{\partial a_2^{(2)}}$. However, the dimensions of $z_2$ are $1 \times 2$, thus there should only be two partial derivatives. It makes conceptual sense to me, that $dz_2$ should equal to $\left[\frac{\partial a_2^{(1)}}{\partial a_2^{(2)}}, \frac{\partial a_2^{(2)}}{\partial a_2^{(1)}} \right]$, but I cannot motivate my intuition. Also, if I generalize this. Suppose $z_2$ is $1 \times 10$, what symbolic expression for derivative: $dz_2$ would we have then?

(I was motivated to implement my neural network from scratch after reading [this](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/) post by Stanford; hence this question).

Another [resource](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/) I am using. I am inclined to believe that $dz_2 = \hat{y}_n - \dot{y}_n$, but why, I do not know ;(

I am also missing $dl_n$ in backprop in $(5)$, the only way to end up at $1 \times 2$, is if we do: $d\hat{y}_n = 1/\hat{y}_n \circ dl_n$.

I have just looked at the porblem in the following way, which did not help me much. We need to find $dz_2  = \frac{\partial L}{ \partial z_2}$, we can rewrite this using backpropagation chain rule $$\begin{align} \frac{\partial L}{ \partial z_2} &= \frac{\partial l_n}{\partial z_2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial l_n} \\ &= \frac{\partial l_n}{\partial z_2} dl_n \\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z_2} \log{(\text{softmax}(z_2))} dl_n \\ &=\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \log{u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z_2} dl_n \\ &= \frac{1}{\text{softmax}(z_2)} \frac{\partial}{\partial z_2} \text{softmax}(z_2) dl_n \end{align}$$

Also, [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815662/backpropagation-softmax-derivative) on Maths.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial derivative of the cost function with respect to the neuron $i$ ,in  the layer $Z_2$ defined in your questions above, is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i}$, where $L$ is the cost function.

please note that the derivation will be on the neuron level not at the layer level, where $z_i$  is the neuron number $i$ in the output layer/softmax layer/ $Z_2$ layer. In other words $Z_2$ layer consists of 2 elements $z_0$ and $z_1$ and the derivation will be w.r.t the neurons/elements.

I re-arrange your equations to keep things as simple as possible: combining equations 5,6,7 yields:

$L = -\ \sum_{n} \dot{y}_n$ x $ log(y_n)$

- Here is a brief derivation

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i}=-\sum_n\dot{y}_n\frac{\partial \log y_n}{\partial z_i}=-\sum_n\dot{y}_n\frac{1}{y_n}\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial z_i}$$

The softmax function $y_n$ is defined as
$$y_n = \frac{e^{z_n}}{\sum_ke^{z_k}}$$

when n=i
$$\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial z_i} = \color{blue}{y_i(1-y_i)}$$
when n <> i 
$$
\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial z_i} = \color{red}{-y_ny_i}$$

now let's substitute $\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial z_i}$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i}=-\dot{y}_i\frac{1}{y_i}\color{blue}{y_i(1-y_i)}-\sum_{n\neq i}\dot{y}_n\frac{1}{y_n}\color{red}{({{-y_ny_i}})}$$
$$
\\=-\dot{y}_i(1-y_i)+\sum_{n\neq i}\dot{y}_n({{y_i}})\\=-\dot{y}_i+{\dot{y}_iy_i+\sum_{n\neq i}\dot{y}_n({y_i})}
\\={y_i\left(\sum_n\dot{y}_n\right)}-\dot{y}_i=y_i-\dot{y}_i$$ where $\sum_n\dot{y}_n = 1$

- For detailed derivation and explanations please see
  https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy

Comment: hi @ahmed, can you elaborate a bit more how you went from the RHS term in the first line to the second line, I can see it has something to do with same indices and different indices. Thanks

Comment: Also, I think the answer should not be dependent on the index of $z_2$, because $2$ here is arbitrary. i.e. $\frac{\partial L }{\partial z_2} \neq y_2 - \dot{y}_2$

Comment: even though $z_2$ is $1 \times 2$, it looks like $\frac{\partial L }{\partial z_2}$ is actually $2 \times 2$... because $\frac{\partial \log{y_n}}{\partial z_2}$ is a derivative of a two dimensional vector with respect to a two dimensional vector.. Oh wait, I may be forgetting about the multiplication by $\dot{y}_n$, which can actually turn it back to be $1 \times 2$

Comment: I will have a look at your link.

Comment: hi @i squared - Keep it Real  , I have edited the answer, the derivation was explained as requested.
one more thing please note that the derivation is on the neuron level not at the layer level, I mean $z_i$  is the neuron number $i$ in the last layer (softmax layer/ $Z_2$ layer). where $Z_2$ layer consists of 2 elements $z_0$ and $z_1$ 

after derivation at the neuron level we can conclude that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial Z_2} = \dot{Y_2}-\hat{Y_2}
$
I used a capital letter to express a matrix/vector and a small letter to express a neuron (or element in the vector)

Comment: thank you so much @ahmed, I will have a look at everything at home!

Comment: Thanks :) Just one thing that I would add here probably. Your $n$ is the class value, whereas in my notation, $n$ represents a training sample. This is very useful. Thanks a bunch again!